# Web Service from WSDL, generated operation has void return type

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am creating a JAX-WS from a WSDL using Netbeans. The WSDL has only one void method and I am not able to figure out how to return the response object.

**WSDL**

```
<wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
        <s:import namespace="http://ns"
    schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" />
        <s:element name="ApplyTransactionRequest" type="at:ApplyTransactionRequest" />
        <s:element name="ApplyTransactionResponse" type="at:ApplyTransactionResponse" /> 
    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="ApplyTransactionRequestMsgXX">
    <wsdl:part name="RequestMsg" element="tns:ApplyTransactionRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ApplyTransactionResponseMsgXX">
    <wsdl:part name="ResponseMsg" element="tns:ApplyTransactionResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>


<wsdl:portType name="ServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="ApplyTransactionRequest">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:ApplyTransactionRequestMsgXX"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ApplyTransactionResponseMsgXX"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="GoaOutboundBinding" type="tns:ServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="ApplyTransactionRequest">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="ApplyTransactionRequest"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="GoaOutboundService">
    <wsdl:port name="GoaOutboundPort" binding="tns:GoaOutboundBinding">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost/Service.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: I think you missed name attribute for input and output elements in port and binding. As example `<wsdl:input name="applyTransReq"...` and `<wsdl:output name="applyTransResp"...` in both places... Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @Vadim adding name did not make much difference